# user input host, startport, endport

Tags: bash, port-scanning

I have an assignment to create a portscanner script in bash. I need to hostname, start port and end port one by one. That is if user input host name, then script should request start port and if host and start port are entered, then script should request stop port. This is my first time learning basg scripting language, so i am a complete beginner. Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

# Basic bash port scanner
# CS 627 Project 1

t=$1
numval=$2
host=$3
startport=$4
stopport=$5

if [[ "$3" = "" ]]; then
    MESSAGE1="please enter host"
    echo $MESSAGE1
    read host

elif [[ "$3" = host && "$4" = "" ]]; then

    MESSAGE2="please enter startport"
    echo $MESSAGE2
    read startport

elif [[ "$4" = startport && "$5" = "" ]]; then

    MESSAGE3="please enter stopport"
    echo $MESSAGE3
    read stopport

elif [[ "$1" = "-t" && "$2" -gt 2 ]]; then

    MESSAGE4="time out changed to $2"
    echo $MESSAGE4

elif [[ "$1" = "-t" && "$2" -eq 2 ]]; then  

    MESSAGE5="time out is $2"
    echo $MESSAGE5

elif [[ "$1" = "-t" && "$2" -lt 2 ]]; then  

    MESSAGE6="time out changed to $2"
    echo $MESSAGE6
fi

function pingcheck
{
ping=`ping -c 1 $host | grep bytes | wc -l`
if [ "$ping" -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "$host is up"
else
    echo "$host is down, quitting"
    exit
fi
}

function portcheck
{
for ((counter=$startport; counter<=$stopport; counter++))
do
    if timeout 2 bash -c "echo >/dev/tcp/$host/$counter"
    then 
        echo "$counter open"
    else
        echo "$counter closed"
    fi
done
}

# first, check that the host is alive
pingcheck
# next, loop through the ports
portcheck
```

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: What's the purpose of `"$3" = host` in `elif [[ "$3" = host && "$4" = "" ]];`? That's testing if the user entered the literal word `host` as the hostname. Why would the user do that? You do the same thing with `startport`, too.

Answer (score 0):

`elif` is normally used for a sequence of mutually exclusive tests. The test in `elif` is only done if the previous `if` or `elif` test failed. You shouldn't use it in your script, because if the user omits the host argument, they've also omitted all the following arguments, and you need to prompt for each of them. So you should do an independent test for each.

There's also no need to test the previous argument. You're testing it against a literal string, but that's not what the user is going to enter.

There's not really any point to those `MESSAGE#` variables. Just echo the prompt, or use the `-p` option to `read`.

Since you assigned named variables to all the parameters at the beginning of the script, you should use those variables in the `if` statements, rather than `$1`, `$2`, etc.

You can simplify the processing of the `-t` option. First, nest the different cases inside a single test for whether `$1` is `-t`. Second, notice that you print the same message for `-gt 2` and `-lt 2`; so there are really only two cases: `-eq 2` and everything else. So you can just use `if` and `else`.

```
if [[ "$host" = "" ]]; then
    echo "please enter host"
    read host
fi

if [[ "$startport" = "" ]]; then
    echo "please enter startport"
    read startport
fi

if [[ "$stopport" = "" ]]; then
    echo "please enter stopport"
    read stopport
fi

if [[ "$t" = "-t" ]]; then
    if [[ "$numval" -eq 2 ]]; then  
        echo "time out is $numval"
    else
        echo "time out changed to $numval"
    fi
fi
```